# Firebase hosting public folder alias

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I have express, react based existing project that I managed to port to Firebase hosting with cloud functions successfully..at least on the dev server.
It looks like this..
This is running on http://localhost:5000/ with command

```
firebase serve --only functions,hosting
```

[image]

Now, when I deploy this, it looks like

[image]

This is NOT a static site. Following the firebase vid here
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOeioOKUKI8

So I have express server running with

```
app.use('/static',express.static('../public'));
```

I had to do this because otherwise, firebase hosting treats each path as public path and it messes up scripts sourcing from public folder and also my react router in react app.

While this works on local server run by firebae, it throws 404 on prod.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

The point is I got all this working on local machine but the deployment just won't oblige.

The deployment was not smooth.

```
firebase deploy
```

didn't work.

```
firebase --only hosting
```

worked.

```
firebase --only functions
```

did not work for quite sometime.

It kept throwing

```
Error setting up the execution environment for your function. Please try again after a few minutes.
```

a few times before it finally worked. And I didn't change anything to make it work. Just did it by itself.

Is there something I am missing? I am very new to firebase hosting.

I already have a production site running somewhere and I wish to port it to firebase. But I can not have random 'try again after a few minutes problems'.

But first things first, why are my static files not rendering on prod when they do on dev?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `public` directory will need to be nested beneath your `functions` folder, as only files within the `functions` folder are deployed to Cloud Functions and available from Node.js.

The local emulator is not actively guarding against this kind of tree navigation, which is why it works locally.

In general, though, you'll likely want to restructure your app a bit so that your static assets are deployed to Firebase Hosting directly rather than being served by Express.

Comment: Thanks Michael,

I found a work around this problem. Say, I have a folder css within public. If I refer to this with absolute path like /css/ it works. It also works with relative path css/ as was explained in the video but that is not a great idea.

The public folder outside is available though if I deploy functions and hosting both. Are you saying I can get away with deploying hosting completely if I move public into functions folder?

Comment: You can but you shouldn't -- Hosting will do a better job caching static assets than you'll be able to do through functions. A combo of Hosting for static and functions for dynamic is the way to go.

Comment: Great answer @MichaelBleigh ... just a question.. how can I create a combo of hosting for static files and function for dynamic ?

Comment: how to get public folder image as a absolute url like, http://localhost:3000/logo.png